# build sklearn error cythonize failed

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cythonize

```
 $ sudo python setup.py build
```

Gives me the following:

```
Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
Generating cython files
Cythonizing sources
sklearn
Processing sklearn/_isotonic.pyx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/scikit-learn/build_tools/cythonize.py", line 198, in <module>
    main(root_dir_arg)
  File "/home/ascikit-learn/build_tools/cythonize.py", line 190, in main
    check_and_cythonize(root_dir)
  File "/home/scikit-learn/build_tools/cythonize.py", line 182, in check_and_cythonize
    cythonize_if_unchanged(cur_dir, cython_file, gen_file, hashes)
  File "/home/scikit-learn/build_tools/cythonize.py", line 156, in cythonize_if_unchanged
    cythonize(full_cython_path, full_gen_file_path)
  File "/home/scikit-learn/build_tools/cythonize.py", line 61, in cythonize
    raise Exception('Building scikit-learn requires Cython >= 0.21')
Exception: Building scikit-learn requires Cython >= 0.21
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 297, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 280, in setup_package
    generate_cython()
  File "setup.py", line 185, in generate_cython
    raise RuntimeError("Running cythonize failed!")
RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!
```

While cython is installed:

```
Processing ./Cython-0.24-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: Cython
  Found existing installation: Cython 0.24
    Uninstalling Cython-0.24:
      Successfully uninstalled Cython-0.24
Successfully installed Cython-0.24
```

Comment: what happens when you do start python and do:

`import cython; print cython.__version__`

?

Comment: This happens: "0.20.1post0". So the version is not 0.24?

Comment: you probably have two versions of cython installed (e.g. in different directories -- could it be that one is system wide and the more recent version in your personal directory ?) and your python interpreter picks up the wrong one. You can check where your imported cython comes from by doing: `import cython; print cython.__file__`

Comment: yep, removed the older version and now I do not receive that error anymore. Thanks